# Jquery EasyUI Tabs Layout

Tags: jquery, tabs, html, jquery-easyui

I'm developing a web application using jQuery EasyUI Tabs.

I've few vertical links on the left side of the application, on click of which new tabs will be added on the horizontal jQuery EasyUI tabs strip on the top.

I've implemented this by using `addTab()` function on the click of the vertical links. This adds a tab with iFrame as its content and loads the child page in this iframe. Everything works fine, but  I don't want to 'contain' the page either vertically or horizontally.

Using jQuery EasyUI tabs forces me to do so, because it comes with jQuery easyUI - tabs - container css, it makes a box in which the iframes are loaded.

Here is what I've right now:

[image: current implementation]

I am planning to make it like this..

[image: planned implementation]

Can someone help me with developing a layout like css which has my header in the north region, bertical links in the west region and a jQuery EasyUI tabs panel in the center region.

Page scroll must be there only for the center region.

Comment: can u provide your code..

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the same, by using `layout` in easyui ... here is the [docs](http://jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#)...

Notice the layout of  documentation itself.... :).. it is the same with what,(i think)  you are asking for.. viewing the source might help you out.. cause i did the same... just make sure.. you leave your center region's widht and height auto (100%).. that will get you the needed scroll bar..

**updated**

using easyui-layout class

```
<div class="easyui-layout" style="width: auto; height: 950px;">
  <div region="west" split="true" title="yourTitle" style="width: 225px;"> //width of left container
      //content of left container
  </div>
  <div id="content" region="center" style="padding: 5px;"> //this is the center part
      <div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs" style="width: auto; height: 900px;">
           //this is center tab part
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: let me know if any problem

Comment: I wanted the same look and feel exactly as in the documentation. I saw this earlier and I was not able to replicate the same for my application. If its ok with you, can you please help me with this code?

Comment: Thanks for the code bipen..
But I've already tried this by seeing from the documentation of easy ui layout plugin..
The problem is, I'm using some jQuery to animate the li items in the west panel..
When i place those li items in easyUI layout and run jQuery on it, it says, 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'nodeName': object is null or undefined'..

I am not able to overcome this problem in layout approach, so I thought there would be some other layout approach other than easyUI layout approach.

Comment: yaa... atleast that will give you a start point.. :) :).. if this helped you , you can accept this as answer..meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks for the code bipen.. But I've already tried this by seeing from the documentation of easy ui layout plugin.. The problem is, I'm using some jQuery to animate the li items in the west panel.. When i place those li items in easyUI layout and run jQuery on it, it says, 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'nodeName': object is null or undefined'.. I am not able to overcome this problem in layout approach, so I thought there would be some other layout approach other than easyUI layout approach